# CSS after event clicked

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqmEAq

I am trying to make the x clicked(x is created after menu plus sign is clicked) and then bringing the dropdown back up.

I have tried

```
a:after:checked ~ .submenu{
  max-height: 999px;
}
```

I know I am close but I can't get the drop bar to go back up when the 'x' is clicked

Comment: I'm a bit confused because in your question, you're talking about the x getting in the way of your dropdown closing, but the CSS that you posted in your question has to do with the `.submenu` height. Please clarify the question so that it pertains to one single issue. If you have another issue, please create a separate question.

Comment: Hey Hunter - sorry about that. I didnt realize it was also my pen too. ill create a separate one thanks!

Comment: If you're able to switch those `a`s to `label`s with `for` attributes, you'll fix the issue. Right now the problem is that the pseudoelement is catching the click (honestly a tad surprised the `a` isn't). A `label` would be more semantically correct, and clicking the pseudoelement would toggle the checkbox. Added bonus, you could then hide the checkboxes and apply styling to the labels instead (which are a lot more conducive to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the x is getting in the way of you opening and closing the menu, then you can add `pointer-events: none;` to your `nav ul > li.sub > a:after`.

**CSS**

```
nav ul > li.sub > a:after {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/mEmwwE)

Comment: hmm im running into a problem when i expand it. is there anyway to set a fixed height on it or something?

Comment: The code that I added did not cause that issue. In the CodePen it is working as expected. Were you having this height issue before?